# Finding $\theta$ given $(x,y)$ no calculator used

Tags: proof-verification

Suppose theta is the angle in standard position whose terminal sides coincide with the point $P(3,4)$. Find $\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)$.

Solution: I tried using the $\arctan$ formula to find the angle that the coordinates will yield, but we won't be allowed to use a calculator in the exam. Is there another way to find $\theta$ without using the calculator? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want your answer as a plain number, or are you okay with having square roots in your final answer?

Comment: I'd be okay with both. Please explain both, if that would be okay

Comment: It'll be hard to get a plain number without a calculator unless you memorized the value of $\sqrt{5}$...